# Defining method to be overriden

Tags: java

I have a method that I'm creating frequently like so:

```
public static SomeObject example () {
  // Create instance of Debug Log class
  // Log first entry
  try {
     // Call specific handler relating to this endpoint
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Other generic calls
  }
}
```

I have noticed that I'm replicating this exact same method every-time I create an endpoint. The one and only difference between each endpoint is the specific handler that is called.

In basic terms I would like to be able to define this method only once, overriding it to change the handler name that is called with everything else remaining the same.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you make the handler an argument of the function?

Comment: You can't override a static method. One basic thing you can do is make this method take a parameter of the handler type.

Comment: Don't make your method static, or just pass in an instance of a type that has a handler method.

Comment: E.g., `public static SomeObject example(TypeWithHandlerMethod obj) { ... try { obj.handle(...); } ... }`

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

You don't need overriding, you need to pass the handler to the method. You should choose the functional interface that best fits your needs.

If the handler takes no arguments and returns no value, it can be a `Runnable`.

If it does produce a value (`SomeObject`?), it can be a `Supplier<SomeObject>`.

Then you can write a single `static` method that calls the method of the chosen functional interface.

For example:

```
public static SomeObject example (Supplier<SomeObject> handler) {
  // Create instance of Debug Log class
  // Log first entry
  try {
     return handler.get();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Other generic calls
  }

  // you might need some return statement here too
}
```

To executethis method, you can pass to it a reference to a method that returns `SomeObject`.

For example:

```
SomeObject result1 = example(SomeClass::someHandlerMethodThatReturnsSomeObject);
SomeObject result2 = example(SomeOtherClass::someOtherHandlerMethodThatReturnsSomeObject);
```

This is assuming `someHandlerMethodThatReturnsSomeObject` and `someOtherHandlerMethodThatReturnsSomeObject` are static methods that have no arguments and return a `SomeObject`. The actual calls may change depending on where the actual logic of your handlers is implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the help!